# how to provide a unzip download to my client

Tags: php

I have a zip file in my server whose name is **don.zip**. In this zip I have **image.jpg** files. Now anyone of my client can click download on that file and will download the **unzip** mode. I mean, on click of download my client should be able to download **image.jpg**.

How can this be possible please? 
Tell me any answer

**my download.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "select * from dow_test where id='$id'";
$query1 = mysql_query($query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
$file_name = $row['file'];
$file_url = $row['file_url'];
$download = new ZipArchive;
$res = $download->open($file_name);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $download->extractTo('C:\Users\Public\Downloads');
  $download->close();
}
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name); 
readfile($download);

}
?>
```

**html**

```
<a href="get1.php?id=12">Download</a>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for a user to download a ZIP and for it to automatically unzip itself on their computer?

Comment: yes exactly please help me

Comment: To my knowledge, that is not possible.

Comment: "my client should be able to download image.jpg" do you mean the server should extract the file from the zip and send it to the client? As others have said, sending the zip to the client and telling it what to do will not work, but extracting files on the server and just sending one file contained in the zip would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine how a downloaded file (yes, even a `.zip`) is handled on a client computer. If you could this would be a security nightmare! All you can do is initiate the download from your php script but this is the end of line.

All you can do is provide users with instructions for them to configure their local file settings to enable automatic unzipping, which will require research and will vary depending on platform, default applications used etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just a try

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "select * from dow_test where id='$id'";
$query1 = mysql_query($query);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
    $file_name = $row['file'];
    $file_url = $row['file_url'];
    $download = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $download->open($file_name);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $download->extractTo('C:\Users\Public\Downloads');
        $download->close();
        unlink($file_name);

$files = find_all_files("foldername");
        $source = "dir/";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = substr($file, strlen("dir/"));
            if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
            if (!is_dir($source.$file)){
                echo '[FILE] '.$source.$file .' -> '.$file . PHP_EOL;
                rename($source.$file, $file);
            }else{
                echo '[DIR]  '.$file . PHP_EOL;
                @mkdir($file);
            }
        }

        // Remove folder dir
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
            if (is_dir($file)){
                echo '[REM]  '.$file . PHP_EOL;
                @rmdir($file);
            }
        }
        @rmdir('./folder');

        // Check if copy was successful
        if(file_exists('index.php')){

            // Redirect 


        }else{
            echo "Oops, that didn\'t work...";
        }
///

    }

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name); 
    readfile($download);
}
?>
```

Comment: zip file direct downloading. i need unzip download